# Unable to set image source programatically in xamarin forms but only when using local images

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-image

I'm trying to create a star-rating implementation and though I would have a star container and dynamically add full stars and half stars to achieve this. I am running into an issue creating an image in code and adding it to a container when using local images however. Displaying an image with the source set in xaml works fine, and creating the image from a url and adding it to the container works fine as well. It is only when I am trying to create an image in code using an image in my resource/drawable folder that it fails.

My code is as follows.

```
Image star = new Image();
star.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("Tamarin_portrait.JPG");
star.HeightRequest = 25;
star.WidthRequest = 25;
star.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
starContainer.Children.Add(star);//No image visible, fails

var star2 = new Image { Source = "Tamarin_portrait.JPG" };
starContainer.Children.Add(star2);
//Ditto above, fails

var webImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png")) };
starContainer.Children.Add(webImage);//Image is displayed correctly


<Image Source="Tamarin_portrait.JPG" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"></Image><!-- In XAML this image display will also work so I know the image itself is valid and available in that drawable folder -->
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? The guide for showing local images suggests I am doing it the right way:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about filename? You should have filename which is valid on all platforms. Try change you filename to lowercase.

That is an information about that in link which you shared.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.